# Loader for a specific section in HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I am kind of newbie in website development, so kind of confused with the behavior of web page.
I want to use loader to hide the image loading in the HTML. In index page I have used tabs view to show the product category and in every category, images are shown. So loading images is taking time and at first it shows all the product images of all categories which is not acceptable. I am talking about a section that is after slider.

[image]

```
                <ul class="nav nav-pills sort-source sort-source-style-3 justify-content-center" data-sort-id="portfolio" data-option-key="filter" data-plugin-options="{'layoutMode': 'fitRows', 'filter': '.custom'}">
                    <li class="nav-item active" data-option-value=".custom"><a class="nav-link text-1 text-uppercase active" href="#">Custom Point of Sale Displays</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-option-value=".wide-format"><a class="nav-link text-1 text-uppercase" href="#">Wide Format printing</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-option-value=".digital"><a class="nav-link text-1 text-uppercase" href="#">Digital small Format</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-option-value=".mailing"><a class="nav-link text-1 text-uppercase" href="#">Mailing</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-option-value=".kitting"><a class="nav-link text-1 text-uppercase" href="#">Kitting & Distribution with Online Tracking</a></li>
                    </ul>

                
                <div class="sort-destination-loader sort-destination-loader-showing mt-4 pt-2">
                    <div  class="row portfolio-list sort-destination lightbox" data-sort-id="portfolio" data-plugin-options="{'delegate': 'a.lightbox-portfolio', 'type': 'image', 'gallery': {'enabled': true}}">
                        <!-- custom point of sales display-->
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item custom">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-no-borders thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-no-borders-rounded thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-bottom-info-dark thumb-info-bottom-info-show-more thumb-info-centered-icons border-radius-0">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
                                        <img src="img/gallery/custom1.png" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                                        <!-- <span class=" thumb-info-title thumb-info line-height-1">Project Title</span>   -->
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="img/gallery/custom1.png" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search text-dark"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item custom">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-no-borders thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-no-borders-rounded thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-bottom-info-dark thumb-info-bottom-info-show-more thumb-info-centered-icons border-radius-0">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
                                        <img src="img/gallery/custom2.png" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                                        <!-- <span class=" thumb-info-title thumb-info line-height-1">Project Title</span> -->  
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="img/gallery/custom2.png" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search text-dark"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- custom displays end-->
                        <!-- wide format starts-->
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item wide-format">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-no-borders thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-no-borders-rounded thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-bottom-info-dark thumb-info-bottom-info-show-more thumb-info-centered-icons border-radius-0">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
                                        <img src="img/gallery/corflutes.png" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                                        <span class=" thumb-info-title thumb-info line-height-1">Corflute Signs</span>  
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="img/gallery/corflutes.png" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search text-dark"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item wide-format">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-no-borders thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-no-borders-rounded thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-bottom-info-dark thumb-info-bottom-info-show-more thumb-info-centered-icons border-radius-0">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
                                        <img src="img/gallery/screenboard.png" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                                        <span class=" thumb-info-title thumb-info line-height-1">Screen Board Signs</span>  
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="img/gallery/screenboard.png" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search text-dark"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item wide-format">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-no-borders thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-no-borders-rounded thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-bottom-info-dark thumb-info-bottom-info-show-more thumb-info-centered-icons border-radius-0">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
                                        <img src="img/gallery/economy.png" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                                        <span class=" thumb-info-title thumb-info line-height-1">Economy Pull Up Banners</span> 
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="img/gallery/economy.png" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search text-dark"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <!-- wide format ends-->
                        
                        
                        <!-- digital small format-->
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item digital">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-no-borders thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-no-borders-rounded thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-bottom-info-dark thumb-info-bottom-info-show-more thumb-info-centered-icons border-radius-0">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
                                        <img src="img/gallery/doorhangers.png" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                                        <span class=" thumb-info-title thumb-info line-height-1">Door Hangers</span>    
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="img/gallery/doorhangers.png" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search text-dark"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item digital">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-no-borders thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-no-borders-rounded thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-bottom-info-dark thumb-info-bottom-info-show-more thumb-info-centered-icons border-radius-0">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
                                        <img src="img/gallery/businesscards.png" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                                        <span class=" thumb-info-title thumb-info line-height-1">Business Cards</span>  
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="img/gallery/businesscards.png" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search text-dark"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item digital">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-no-borders thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-no-borders-rounded thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-bottom-info-dark thumb-info-bottom-info-show-more thumb-info-centered-icons border-radius-0">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
                                        <img src="img/gallery/flyers.png" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                                        <span class=" thumb-info-title thumb-info line-height-1">Flyers</span>  
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="img/gallery/flyers.png" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search text-dark"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- digital displays end-->
                        
                        <!-- mailing -->
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item mailing">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-no-borders thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-no-borders-rounded thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-bottom-info-dark thumb-info-bottom-info-show-more thumb-info-centered-icons border-radius-0">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
                                        <img src="img/gallery/mailing.png" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="img/gallery/mailing.png" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search text-dark"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item mailing">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-no-borders thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-no-borders-rounded thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-bottom-info-dark thumb-info-bottom-info-show-more thumb-info-centered-icons border-radius-0">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper border-radius-0">
                                        <img src="img/gallery/mailing2.png" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="img/gallery/mailing2.png" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search text-dark"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- mailing ends-->
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Check the video I have uploaded. Then you will get an idea. The problem is it is working fine in my pc as well but you cant give the same reason to client. So I need to find solution of this problem

Comment: Hello sir. check the video carefully and the fully loaded page. This is the video sent by my client. In the video you can see products of all 7 categories but actually in fully loaded page one can see only Custom point of sale Displays. Got my point?

Comment: Probably you already checked, but did your client clear his cache before checking the page? Perhaps he is seeing old code...? [How to clear cache in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/a/512833/131214) -- *make sure you review that link.*

Comment: He has checked it for the very first time

Comment: So, to be clear - Did your client actually clear the cache, and did that make any difference? Is the result still the same? Does he still see the bad results?

Comment: Sir, this is not an issue of cache memory, it happens because of slow connection and I can say this to my one client but client can't say this to each visitor of the website

Comment: Does the website "adjust" and hide the extra images after a few seconds? Or do the extra product images remain visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that perhaps your client has not cleared his cache, and so is running old code. He can clear the cache by following [these instructions](https://superuser.com/a/512833/131214).

---

If the above did not fix the problem:

This is a kludge, because I don't know your full HTML/javascript code, but:

Perhaps you can hide the section with the category images for a second or two, and then allow it to be displayed when appropriate:

```
 .sort-destination-loader.sort-destination-loader-showing{display:none;}
```

and in javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.sort-destination-loader.sort-destination-loader-showing').show();
},3000); //allow display after 3 seconds
```

If that works, then step-back the `,3000` until it is as short a delay as possible:

```
},500); //allow display after 1/2 second
```

*Perhaps this would solve the problem temporarily while you are working on understanding the full problem?*

Comment: i haven't tried this because client wants permanent solution. Thank you for the solution

Comment: Have you personally tested this on the client's machine? I ask because sometimes the client will say, *"Yes, I cleared the cache as you asked"* when, in fact, he didn't do it correctly. Are you *certain* that the cache is not the problem? *Just asking...* It is always possible to tell the client that you cannot reproduce an error on your machine and ask if you can do a remote test (via [join.me](https://www.join.me/), or [any of these](https://www.lifewire.com/free-remote-access-software-tools-2625161) or [these ones](https://www.wikihow.com/Access-Another-Computer-from-Your-Computer))

Answer (score 0):

while browsing your website from my computer, it seems to me you everything is ok according to your issue. It may happen for my fast internet. The loading time of your website can't take extra time in my computer. By the way, I can suggest you wrap hole body tag under a div. After then add a unique id with your wrap div. Afterwards, just apply some jquery code against id when all document load properly. Let me know, yet you can't finish the issue.

Comment: Hello Sir, You got my question properly. Thank you. But I want to know how to do this as I am newbie in this field. You can also check the video that I have uploaded. The website is working fine in my pc as well but you cant give the same reason to client. So I need to find solution of this problem